ARM (Azure Resource Manager) template failing in pipeline
I am trying to update the configurations when creating a new site on Azure. My goal is to Change the minimum TLS Cipher Suite from TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (least secure) to TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.
Running the least secure is no problem. But when changing to TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, my pipeline fails. I can do it from Powershell locally.
I have tried using AzurePowerShell@4 and AzurePowerShell@5
 - task: AzurePowerShell@4
   inputs:
     azureSubscription:xx
     ScriptType: 'FilePath'
     ScriptPath: xx
     ScriptArguments: xx
     azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

I see that I have provided too little information. Sorry about that.
Locally I'm running PowerShell version 5.1.19041.4412
Agent: Azure Pipelines
Image: windows-latest PowerShell Version: 5.1.20348.2400
I'm getting this error when updating the functions in the Function App.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Retrying after 10 seconds
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Retrying after 10 seconds
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
##[error]The function call failed 3 times. Failing step
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

The specific section that fails in my arm template is
 "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
 "http20Enabled": false,
 "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
 "minTlsCipherSuite": "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
 "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
 "reservedInstanceCount": 0

Where changing minTlsCipherSuite from TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA -> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 giving the error message above.
##[debug]Error record:
##[debug]PackageManagement\Save-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Az'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
##[debug]At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:11794 char:21
##[debug]+             $null = PackageManagement\Save-Package @PSBoundParameters
##[debug]+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ets.SavePackage:SavePackage) [Save-Package], Exceptio    n
##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.SavePackage
##[debug] 
##[debug]Script stack trace:
##[debug]at Save-Module<Process>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1: line 11794
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b\4.240.6\TryMakingModuleAvailable.ps1: line 75
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931\4.240.6\azurepowershell.ps1: line 53
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
##[debug]Exception:
##[debug]System.Exception: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Az'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.


my pipeline fails - can you please edit your question and paste the error message?

Which Powershell version(s) are being used in your local machine and build agent?

Hi there, Welcome to SO. Can you please share your PowerShell script or commands that you ran to Change the minimum TLS Cipher Suite for your site? Your current post doesn't include such info. Besides what was the error in your pipeline logs? Can you please add $DebugPreference = 'Continue' in this script to show more debug logs? Thx.

Are you using a Microsoft-hosted or self-hosted Windows agent to run this pipeline?

I am using Microsoft-hosted/Azure agent running on Windows latest

Thanks for the update. From the current error message that No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Az', Did your observe the ARM deployment even got started? What were the commands or script you ran in the AzurePowerShell task, New-AzResourceGroupDeployment? The error cannot be reproduced if you run a simple command Get-AzContext right? So can you please share the minimal and reproducing script to let us know which part in it was affected?
